# Create an Invoice in Coupa via the API

Tags: coupa

I am trying to find a POST function for the Coupa API to create an Invoice but the documentation doesnt include anything just wondering if anyone on here has had the same problem?

I noted that some of the middleware vendor e.g Microsoft power automate have user create flows that do it but just wondering what the actual function is so i can test it in Postman. sorry for the limited info im not super tech any help appreciated.